# No module error : "ImportError: cannot import name util"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ros, python-importlib

I am getting the following error when I run my code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ros_colour_node.py", line 26, in <module>
    from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
  File "/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/ROS-label-node/detectron2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .utils.env import setup_environment
  File "/home/nvidia/catkin_ws/src/ROS-label-node/detectron2/utils/env.py", line 3, in <module>
    from importlib import util
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

I am using python2.7 to run my code on ROS melodic on jetson xavier NX with ubuntu 18.04.
I have installed the importlib library directly but it cant seem to find the util module.
I am trying to run instance segmentation using ROS on JEtson. I have tried to run the code from the following repo [Segmentation](https://github.com/SfTI-Robotics/ROS-label-node)

Comment: Why python2 when they stopped support it more than year ago

Comment: From the requirements of the linked repository: "Python ≥ 3.6".  So it will likely not work with Python 2.  If possible, I suggest to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic which supports Python 3.  You may also be able to use Python 3 with Melodic one way or the other but since it is not officially supported, it will be probably a constant hassle.

Comment: @luator Jetson does not support ubuntu 20.04 yet htrough jetpack, so I cant install ros noetic on it. What do you suggest instead?

Comment: I think there won't be an easy and nice solution.  You may have success building Melodic with Python 3 (see, for example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1502191/how-to-use-ros-melodic-with-python-3)).  If it is just for a single node, an alternative might be to implement the ROS-related stuff in C++ and add Python bindings (if this is feasible depends on the complexity of your application).
Or switch to ROS 2, which uses Python 3.  However, depending on your setup this might be a big effort.

Comment: @luator As I am quite new at ROS im not very comfortable yet with converting to C++ and then attaching the python bindings. Do you know which is the latest version of Jetpack which supports pytorch for python2?

Comment: @AkshayAcharya Sorry, I don't know anything about Jetson/Jetpack.